# How to handle null Pointer Exception after applying Spring data query?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have below snippet of code.

```
 TestMsgCenter msgLog = TestMsgCenter.findByIp("localhost")
        if (msgLog != null) {
            msgLog.setClothDate(new Date())
            msgLog.merge()
        } else {
            
           msgLog.setClothType("Lets")
           msgLog.setClothDate(new Date())
           msgLog.setClothId("Go")
           msgLog.save()
        }
```

How to handle null case in above else block?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a values to a null object.
You need to instantiate one:

```java
 TestMsgCenter msgLog = TestMsgCenter.findByIp("localhost")
        if (msgLog != null) {
            msgLog.setClothDate(new Date())
            msgLog.merge()
        } else {
           msgLog = new MsgLog();  //here
           msgLog.setClothType("Lets")
           msgLog.setClothDate(new Date())
           msgLog.setClothId("Go")
           msgLog.save()
        }
```

Comment: I agree your solution but it is Spring data object. Is there a need of instantiating nevertheless?

Comment: Hi. If this object is an Entity then it has to be instantiated, it's not a spring bean.